# How can I update the gapi.client.drive.FilesResource.list method to support the parameter 'driveId'?

Tags: google-drive-api, angular8

From an Angular 8 component I am trying to do a file search on a team drive using the following method:

```js
getFiles(folderId: string) {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        pageSize: 100,
        corpora: 'drive',
        driveId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        includeTeamDriveItems: true,
        fields: "nextPageToken, files(*)",
        q: `'${folderId}' in parents and trashed = false`,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
    }).then((res) => {
        let files: FileInfo[] = [];
        res.result.files.forEach((file) => files.push(FileInfo.fromGoogleFile(file)));
        return files;
    });
}
```

I have the following error:

Object literal may only specify known properties, and **'driveId' does not exist in type** '{ alt?: string; corpora?: string; corpus?: string; fields?: string; includeTeamDriveItems?: boolean; key?: string; oauth_token?: string; orderBy?: string; pageSize?: number; pageToken?: string; prettyPrint?: boolean; ... 5 more ...; userIp?: string; }'.ts(2345)

Using the "Try this API" utility, I call this method in live data and get an API response.

Could someone help me solve this problem.

Many thanks

Comment: `includeTeamDriveItems` is deprecated use `includeItemsFromAllDrives` instead. A part from that this error seems very weird to me. Could you explain how are you invoking the API? Which version? What version of the library are you using?

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. The GAPI version is gapi@0.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Thank a lot.

It is already resolved despite continuing to show me the message "'driveId' does not exist in type".